# What does $(\log n) \cdot (\log n)$ simplify to in Big O notation?

Tags: big-o-notation

Does it simplify to $O(\log n)$ or $O(\log^2 n)$ or something else entirely? I am a bit stuck on this one.

Comment: While $O(n)$ looks the most simple upper bound, you may be looking for a tight one - $\Theta$.

Answer (score 2):

As $\log(n) \times \log(n) = \log^2(n)$, you can say $\log(n) \times \log(n) = O(\log^2(n))$.Moreover, as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{\log^2(n)} = 0$, you can't write $\log(n) \times \log(n) = O(\log(n))$, but you can write $\log(n) \times \log(n) = \omega(\log(n))$.

Answer (score 0):

One more way of approaching these type of questions if you have slightest idea of possible answers is as follows:

The questions is: What does $(log $ n).($log $ n) simplify to in Big O notation(By Big O I assume you mean the tightest upper bound)

The possible answers provided are: $(log $ n) and $O(log^2$ n)

Solution: Let us take log of all the above three terms

1. $log ((log $ n).($log $ n)) = $loglog$ n + $loglog$ n = 2$(loglog$ n)
2. $log (log$ n) = $loglog$ n
3. $log (log^2$ n) = 2($loglog$ n)

Don't ignore the constants after taking the log.

You can now clearly see that:

($log $ n).($log $ n) = $O$($log^2$ n)

and

($log $ n).($log $ n) = ($log$ n)